# How to provide class/object methods in a block in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Sometimes you can see:

```
do_this do
   available_method1 "arg1"
   available_method2 "arg1"
end
```

When I use the block from do_this method then I get some methods I could use inside that block.

I wonder how this is accomplished? How does the code look like behind the scenes?

I want to be able to provide some methods through a block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a Domain-Specific Language (DSL). [Here's](http://www.daniel-azuma.com/blog/view/z3bqa0t01uugg1/implementing_dsl_blocks) [(Last archived version)](https://web.archive.org/web/20100426173757/http://www.daniel-azuma.com/blog/view/z3bqa0t01uugg1/implementing_dsl_blocks)  some great info on various forms of Ruby DSL blocks.

There are really two ways to go about doing this, with different syntaxes:

```
do_thing do |thing| # with a block parameter
  thing.foo :bar
  thing.baz :wibble
end

# versus

do_thing do # with block-specific methods
  foo :bar
  baz :wibble
end
```

The first is more explicit and less likely to fail, while the second is more concise.

The first can be implemented like so, by simply passing a new instance as the block parameter with `yield`:

```
class MyThing
  def self.create
    yield new
  end

  def foo(stuff)
    puts "doing foo with #{stuff}"
  end
end

MyThing.create do |thing|
  thing.foo :bar
end
```

And the second, which runs the block in the context of the new object, giving it access to `self`, instance variables, and methods:

```
class MyThing
  def self.create(&block)
    new.instance_eval &block
  end

  def foo(stuff)
    puts "doing foo with #{stuff}"
  end
end

MyThing.create do
  foo :bar
end
```

And if you really want to do it without calling `MyThing.create`, just:

```
def create_thing(&block)
  MyThing.create &block
end
```

Comment: Are there any sources with this kind of examples? It would be good to have various design patterns described with ruby code like this.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually done using `instance_eval` to change the value of `self` inside the block to be some different object, which then handles those method calls.

As a quick example:

```
class ExampleReceiver
  def available_method1 arg ; p [:available_method1, arg] ; end
  def available_method2 arg ; p [:available_method2, arg] ; end
end
def do_this(&blk) ; ExampleReceiver.new.instance_eval(&blk) ; end

do_this do
  available_method1 "arg1" #=> [:available_method1, "arg1"]
  available_method2 "arg1" #=> [:available_method2, "arg1"]
end
```

Though this is a powerful language feature, and has been used before to great effect, there is still some debate on whether it's a good idea or not.  If you don't know what's going on, you might be surprised that the value of `@some_instance_variable` changes inside and outside the block, since it's relative to the current value of `self`.

See [Daniel Azuma's excellent article](http://dazuma.github.io/blockenspiel/rdoc/ImplementingDSLblocks_rdoc.html) for more discussion and details.

Comment: link to the article leads to `404 not found` error